# How i put 2 effects in my video strip?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I've tried to put two effect strips in the video strip, but it's only working the effect strips that stays on top. How can I make the two effects work at the same time?

[image: translate effect strip]

[image: blur effect strip]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an effect strip, that strip essentially replaces the input strip. So add your transform strip, then--with that transform strip selected--add the gaussian blur.

[image]